# Intertwiner in german?

Tags: group-theory, terminology

What is the best way to translate the mathematical term ''intertwiner'' (between two representations of a group) into German?

Comment: [Pretty related](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/46061/what-is-the-german-translation-for-intertwiner).

Comment: Which horrible university forces you to give lectures in German ;) Anyway, naively I would try to take any translation of entwine and incorporate inter

Comment: Taking J.S. Milne's [11th tip](http://www.jmilne.org/math/tips.html) one step further? :-)

Comment: @SimonMarkett: I'd guess an university in Germany (or another country where German is the native language). You generally expect lectures to be given in the native language, don't you?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Milne forgot to add explanatory notes to the 11th tip. German is not a bad languague for expressing mathematics.

Comment: @celtschk In fact I got my masters (actually Diplom) from a German university. From the third year on basically all my lectures were in English and I am _really_ happy about this. Makes things a lot easier now.

Comment: @Arnold: I think you are missing the obvious humor in his post.

Comment: Is this what "Homomorphismus von Darstellungen" is? I think it is but I'm not very familiar with the subject.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I have people complaining about german being hard to learn and listen to at least 3 times a week, so it's not really funny. (Unless you're [Mark Twain](http://www.crossmyt.com/hc/linghebr/awfgrmlg.html).)

Comment: @celtschk my university (in Germany) gives all its masters lectures in English. Next year they will begin moving the bachelors classes over to English.

Comment: Personally, I don't like the word 'intertwiner'; I don't think this concept deserves a special name. I prefer G-morphism, or k[G]-linear map, or something like that (and these have obvious translations into other languages).

Answer (score 3):

Excuse me if mine is a very low-brow approach.

Let us look at the English Wikipedia page Equivariant Maps (cf. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivariant_map)), where there is the definition of Interwiners, as a special kind of equivariant maps.
Then let us switch to the German version, and we find that, in the same context, it is  employed just the term *äquivarianten Abbildung*.

I hope it helps. Bye.

**Edit** Added because the OP need not only tranlations but references to actual usage.
In the German literature you'll find it also in the abbreviated form *$G$-Abbildung* as for example [here](http://books.google.it/books?id=ynLNVC84oQcC&pg=PA41&lpg=PA41&dq=G-Abbildung&source=bl&ots=vqPulkz6im&sig=AUiIVOiFwcywgl1_0EVgG-Fvo-E&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RzEHULLnHOmh4gTO49n3CA&sqi=2&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=G-Abbildung&f=false%5d) in Tammo Von Dieck's Topologie,
(In order to overcome the difficulties you report in comments, here is the exact physical reference: Chapter I, Section 10, second paragraph on page 41.)

Comment: I had done just that before posting the question, but I would have liked to have a single word translation rather than 9 syllables. - Would the term ''äquivariante Abbildung'' also be appropriate for intertwiners between representations of an algebra?

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier I have added a reference using just *G-Abbildung*.

Comment: google books says that it is not avialable to me for viewing. Could you please give the page number?

Comment: From Google Books (to me the page was displayed): [40](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FtMwG.png)
[41](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5wJcS.png)
[42](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kKC6J.png)

Answer (score 3):

The link [What is the german translation for intertwiner?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/46061) provided by [Nick Kidman](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172408/intertwiner-in-german/172426#comment396135_172408) was quite useful. I found two old German papers by authorities in group theory:

- R. Brauer, Eine Bedingung für vollständige Reduzibilität von Darstellungen gewöhnlicher und infinitesimaler Gruppen, Mathematische Zeitschrift 41 (1936), 330–339 [Link](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01180422)
- O. Tamaschke, Ringtheoretische Behandlung einfach transitiver Permutationsgruppen. Mathematische Zeitschrift 73 (1960), 393-408.
  who use on p.406 "verkettet" for the relationship, which suggests the name Verketter, which can indeed be found in recent lecture notes by
- K.-H. Rehren, [Konforme Quantenfeldtheorie](https://www.theorie.physik.uni-goettingen.de/papers/rehren/cqft9798.pdf),
  although Rehren subsequently uses the word Intertwiner as a German Lehnswort for this concept.

Edit:
p.273 of [arXiv:hep-th/9805093v1](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9805093v1) explicitly says 'intertwiners (“Verketter” in the sense of Schur)', and Schur was probably the first one to use the concept at all. Indeed, in his paper "[Beiträge zur Theorie der Gruppen linearer homogener Substitutionen](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1988680)", Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 10 (1909), 159–175, Schur uses in this context the adjective "verkettet", but not the substantive.

Edit2: Hermann Boerner uses in Chapter 3 of his book
Darstellungstheorie der Endlichen Gruppen, Vieweg, Wiesbaden 1967, the term 'Verkettungsmatrix'.

Answer (score 2):

My old Technik-Wörterbuch (1982) directs me from intertwine to interlace, which it translates by *verschlingen* (*Verschlingung*, *verschlungener Zyklus*), which I think sounds right. These words are marked as topological terms, though, so you will have to consider if they are suitable in an algebraic context.

Comment: It is not enough to find possible translations; since the concept is old one also needs references for actual usage in this context. (Verschlingung sounds more like braiding, which has a very different meaning in group theory.)